# Popuplating a form field with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, forms

is it possible to populate a form field using javascript where the id changes every time the page is loaded? can it be tarteted by name rather than id?

thanks

Comment: Certainly that is possible. I suggest you simply take a look at the documentation of selectors, easiest probably at the beginning is to use the `jQuery` library for such things: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[name=element_name]").val('Put your value');
```

Comment: This is _not_ vanilla javascript.

Comment: document.getElementsByName('element_name').val('Put your value');

Comment: "Unless another tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected."

Answer (score 0):

The vanilla javascript variant for this would be something like:

```
var xyz = document.getElementsByName("xyz");
xyz.value = "some value";
```

Or, if you do not need any other access to that element the shorter version:

```
document.getElementsByName("xyz").value = "some value";
```

However often it is easier to use a javascript library like `jQuery` or similar. In that case you'd use something like that, but you have to include the library first:

```
$('[name="xyz"]').val("some value");
```